# getTestCaseList only for enabled test cases

Tags: groovy, soapui

I would like to have a test case list containing only enabled test cases in the tear down script. I tried below code. however it return all the test cases including the disabled ones.

```
project.getTestSuiteList().each {
    it.getTestCaseList().each { tcList ->
        tcList.each {
log.info it.properties
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
project.getTestSuiteList().each {
    it.getTestCaseList().each { tcList ->
        tcList.each {
if(!it.isDisabled()){
/*do your stuff*/
}

}
```

Comment: Your example will let him do "stuff" on the _disabled_ testcases. I think you may want to add a "!" to make your if look like : if (!it.isDisable())

Answer (score 1):

your testCase, same as at testStep level, has a 'disabled' property

```
        tcList.each{
        log.info it.name
        log.info it.disabled
        ...
    }
```

Then you can set condition on it ...